# Why downcast array item in Swift?

Tags: swift, downcast

Why must I downcast an array item in Swift, if the sub-class of the array item is known?

```
 > class B {let t: String = "-B-"}
 > class B1:B {let t1: String = "-B1-"}
 > class B2:B {let t2: String = "-B2-"}
 > let bunch = [B(), B1(), B2()]
```

As expected:

```
 > print(type(of:bunch))
 Array<B>
```

The sub-class of each element of the array is known:

```
 > for item in bunch {print(type(of:item))}
 B
 B1
 B2
```

Yet (as documented) we cannot access the item's sub-class member, and we have to down-class:

```
> if bunch[1] is B1 {let b1 = bunch[1] as! B1; print(b1.t1)} 
-B1-
```

because this does not work:

```
> bunch[1].t1
error: repl.swift:17:6: error: value of type 'B' has no member 't1'; did you mean 't'?
```

Why can Swift determine the sub-class using type(of:) but it cannot infer it when accessing a member in that sub-class? Is it a bug, a historic hang-over, or am I missing something?

Comment: How should the *compiler* know that `bunch[1]` is a `B1` (but `bunch[2]` is not)?

Comment: @MartinR yes now that makes sense. Within a loop `if item is B1 {let b1 = item as?B1; print(b1.t1)}` is valid because b1 is cast as a B1 and so it has b1.t1, while item, as compiled but not run, may or may not have a t1. Great insight, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift arrays are collections of items of a *single type.* The type of the array

```
let bunch = [B(), B1(), B2()]
```

is inferred as `[B]` because `B` is the “nearest common superclass” of the given three elements. Consequently, `bunch[1]` has the type `B` and not `B1`. That is why `bunch[1].t1` does not compile.

Of course you can print the actual type of an array element at runtime with `type(of:)`, or check it against `B1`. The latter is better done with optional binding:

```
if let b1 = bunch[1] as? B1 {
    print(b1.t1)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps one addition: the array elements must have a same type that can be determined at compile time. This is a fundamental requirement, so that iterators can operate with predetermined types. In my particular case it is inferred from the "let" literal (If I used  var, I would have had to set it to type [B] in order to house B, B1 and B2)

Comment: @P2000: It makes no difference if the array is `let` or `var`: If you don't annotate the type explicitly then it is inferred from the context, i.e. from the right-hand side.

Comment: Yes. What I meant was that this case is pronounced if the elements are not literal (so not as in the example's let - or a similar var), but -as you clarified- are inserted into the array during runtime. I obscured it a bit due to the literal, and that was precisely how it became a question for me. Thank you for your help today.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that once you declare the array of type `B` then the compiler treats all the elements in the array to be of type `B` and will not automatically infer methods based on any subclasses present. It seems you are wondering why the compiler/array is not smart enough to determine the class of a `let` declared array, when in theory it could be. I'm not sure many languages support such a feature, in any event you can do the same thing by simply unwrapping it like you did, since YOU know it in this case.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  "when in theory it could be" is what I initially thought too, but in fact it cannot be determined at compile time, as Martin writes in his comment. "I'm not sure many languages support such a feature": indeed, I think it is for the realm of interpreted/scripted languages, where it is irrelevant whether a loop item has a .t1 member or not, until the loop is run and that point in code is reached.